# use nodebox as a module for python 3.5

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyglet, nodebox

I'm trying to import everything from nodebox.graphics into my python 3.5 code but I get errors:

- > ImportError: No module named 'bezier'

To mention, this module exists in nodebox/graphics. As I searched in python documentations, I have to add the nodebox and pyglet folders into the directory of my code but that did not work.

I also didn't succeed in adding them to system directories.

How can I solve the problem and run my code properly?

P.S. I'm currently using ubuntu 16.04 if it matters.

Comment: `sudo apt install python3-matplotlib` ... Provides `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/bezier.py`

Comment: it did not work @KnudLarsen

Comment: More "bezier" ... https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bezier.py ... You can also do 1) `sudo apt install apt-file` ... 2) `apt-file search bezier.py` ... and Google https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/canvas/bezier.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. Placing all the .py files except (and this is important) the __init__.py file in the main libraries folder fixed it for me. The final path should look like ~/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bezier.py